# CSS Smooth end of an animation

Tags: css, animation

I have made this loader bar. Is it possible that when I remove the class "animate" to wait the animation to end?

Or just make the bar fade out (it should now but the animation stops).

I thought to let the animation run continuously and fade the bar's colours but i don't like to leave an animation always running....

I don't really like that it just disappears :(

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $(".loadBar").addClass("animate");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".loadBar").removeClass("animate");
  }, 5000)
})
```

```css
#btn {
  margin-top: 50px;
}


.loadBar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 4;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity ease-in 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity ease-in 1s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in 1s;
  transition: opacity ease-in 1s;
}

.loadBar .bar {
  content: "";
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transition: left 2s 2s;
  -o-transition: left 2s 2s;
  -webkit-transition: left 2s 2s;
  transition: left 2s 2s;
}

.loadBar .bar:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #4183D7;
}

.loadBar .bar:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.loadBar .bar:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.loadBar.animate .bar {
  -moz-transition: left 0s 0s;
  -o-transition: left 0s 0s;
  -webkit-transition: left 0s 0s;
  transition: left 0s 0s;
}

.loadBar.animate .bar:nth-child(1) {
  -moz-animation: loading 1.5s infinite;
  -o-animation: loading 1.5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: loading 1.5s infinite;
  animation: loading 1.5s infinite;
}

.loadBar.animate .bar:nth-child(2) {
  -moz-animation: loading 1.5s 0.5s infinite;
  -o-animation: loading 1.5s 0.5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: loading 1.5s 0.5s infinite;
  animation: loading 1.5s 0.5s infinite;
}

.loadBar.animate .bar:nth-child(3) {
  /* -moz-animation   : loading 3s linear 2s infinite;
    -o-animation     : loading 3s linear 2s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: loading 3s linear 2s infinite;
    animation        : loading 3s linear 2s infinite;*/
}

.loadBar.animate {
  opacity: 1;
}

@-moz-keyframes loading {
  from {
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loading {
  from {
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes loading {
  from {
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="loadBar">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>


<button id="btn">Show loadbar</button>
```

Comment: You can run animation continuously and hide element after fading out animation will be completed so browser will know that it should not run animation on this element.

Answer (score 2):

Well currently your animation doesnt end...

```
animation: loading 1.5s 0.5s infinite;
```

so lets fix that by making it iterate 1 time:

```
animation: loading 1.5s 0s 1;
```

Because its one iteration and no delay the overall animation runtime is 1500ms...so you set the timeout to 1500ms like so...

EDIT: Because you also specified (in the comments to this answer) that you would want the animation to continue until ajax has loaded I have amended my code to do so

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  doajax();

})

function doajax() {

  $(".loadBar").addClass("animate");


  //every 1500ms check if ajax has done loading
  setInterval(function() {
    if ($(".loadBar").hadClass("page-loaded")) {
      $(".loadBar").removeClass("animate");
    }
  }, 1500);



  $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.mypage/",
    type: "POST",
    data: "",
    success: function(data) {
      $(".loadBar").addClass("page-loaded");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#btn {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.loadBar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 4;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity ease-in 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity ease-in 1s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in 1s;
  transition: opacity ease-in 1s;
}

.loadBar .bar {
  content: "";
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transition: left 2s 2s;
  -o-transition: left 2s 2s;
  -webkit-transition: left 2s 2s;
  transition: left 2s 2s;
}

.loadBar .bar:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #4183D7;
}

.loadBar .bar:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.loadBar .bar:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.loadBar.animate .bar {
  -moz-transition: left 0s 0s;
  -o-transition: left 0s 0s;
  -webkit-transition: left 0s 0s;
  transition: left 0s 0s;
}

.loadBar.animate .bar:nth-child(1) {
  -moz-animation: loading 1.5s 2;
  -o-animation: loading 1.5s 2;
  -webkit-animation: loading 1.5s 2;
  animation: loading 1.5s 2;
}

.loadBar.animate .bar:nth-child(2) {
  -moz-animation: loading 1.5s 0.5s 2;
  -o-animation: loading 1.5s 0.5s 2;
  -webkit-animation: loading 1.5s 0.5s 2;
  animation: loading 1.5s 0.5s 2;
}

.loadBar.animate .bar:nth-child(3) {
  /* -moz-animation   : loading 3s linear 2s infinite;
    -o-animation     : loading 3s linear 2s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: loading 3s linear 2s infinite;
    animation        : loading 3s linear 2s infinite;*/
}

.loadBar.animate {
  opacity: 1;
}

@-moz-keyframes loading {
  from {
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loading {
  from {
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes loading {
  from {
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="loadBar">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>


<button id="btn">Show loadbar</button>
```

Comment: OK, but i don't know how much the duration will be because i switch the class on the start/end of an async ajax call..

Comment: @marcoburrometo ah I see! I have an idea for that! amend your question with the ajax and I will show you :)

Comment: Maybe something like this, binding to the animationEnd evt: http://jsfiddle.net/u7vXT/

Comment: @marcoburrometo well that still wouldnt fix your problem with ajax and im not sure how well supported animationEnd is so I wouldnt recommend it :) I have however, amended my code to work with ajax so as you can see it will keep the animation going until ajax has been successful :)

Comment: brilliant! glad you got a solution :)